# Diameter of set of vectors that have at least inner product $1-\epsilon$ with a unit vector

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis, jacobian

Let $V$ be a real inner product space and let $v\in V$ be a unit vector. Consider the set $S_\epsilon:=\{w\in V: ||w||=1 \text{ and } \langle v,w\rangle\geq 1-\epsilon\}$ for small $\epsilon >0$. I want to know in general what is the diameter of this set. In two dimension I have drawn the following so that my calculation becomes clear:

[image]

I want to first compute the length of the straight line between $v$ and $w$. Assume $v$ and $w$ are unit vectors such that $\langle v,w\rangle=\cos (\theta)=1-\epsilon$. Then it follows that $\theta=O(\sqrt{\epsilon})$. We have that this straight line between $v$ and $w$ has length $2\sin(\theta)=O(\sqrt{\epsilon})$. The only thing left is to find the Jacobian of the diffeomorphism that maps this straight line on the circle between $v$ and $w$.

I do not know much about this. So I would like to ask the following:

- Does this Jacobian do much to the $O(\sqrt{\epsilon})$?
- If so what is this Jacobian (asymptotic value is enough)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may assume ${\bf v}={\bf e}_1$. Then $S_\epsilon$ is a spherical cap:
$$S_\epsilon=\bigl\{{\bf x}\in V\,\bigm|\,|{\bf x}|=1, \ x_1\geq 1-\epsilon\bigr\}\ .$$
The base of this cap is a  ball of codimension $1$ and radius $\sqrt{1-(1-\epsilon)^2}=\sqrt{2\epsilon-\epsilon^2}$. I claim that the diameter of $S_\epsilon$ is given by
$${\rm diam}(S_\epsilon)=2\sqrt{2\epsilon-\epsilon^2}\ .$$
*Proof.* Let ${\bf x}=(x_1,{\bf x}')$, ${\bf y}=(y_1,{\bf y}')\in S_\epsilon$, $1-\epsilon\leq \ x_1\leq y_1$. Then $|{\bf x}-{\bf y}|$ is enlarged if ${\bf y}'$ is turned opposite to ${\bf x}'$ in the orthogonal complement of ${\bf e}_1$ . We now choose ${\bf e}_2$ parallel to ${\bf x}'$, so that for all practical purposes
$${\bf x}=(x_1,\sqrt{1-x_1^2}),\qquad{\bf y}=(y_1,-\sqrt{1-y_1^2})\ .$$
The claim now follows from inspection of a simple 2D figure.